# Motor control using arduino/raspberry pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm new to robotics. I would like to know if 56 output lines can be taken from an arduino or raspberry pi?

Comment: What does output lines mean? Analog? Digital? PWM?...

Comment: Digital output lines

Comment: how about you look at the docs for the arduino and raspberry to find how many they have??

Answer (score 2):

From the Arduinos only the "DUE" will work.
It has 54 Digital IOs and 2 Analog Outputs.

The newest raspberry has "only" 40 IOs, so it won't fit your specs.

Another possibility would be the "BeagleBone Black" with up to 69 IOs.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/product/model-b-plus/ 
http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack 
http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Main/ArduinoBoardDue